# Tagging images/photos for quick searching

Tags: photos, images

I've got a bazillion images that I have no time to scroll for if I need to show something, and I'm considering to give them tags to identify them.

For example, I have a photo of a receipt. I want to add tags of the name of the store-purchased, name of the brand, name of the item. So if I have to show an accountant or tax guy, I can quickly retrieve the image using its tags.

Is there any way to tag photos and later search for them? 3rd-party apps are also allowed.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site for Android end-users to solve their issues. Explicit app recommendation is off-topic here. The question has been reworded to suit the site's policy while still allowing answers to recommend apps. On the other hand, if you're only interested in apps, you might check our sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please ensure to follow [their guideline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get the most suitable app to your query. Also, consider taking a quick [tour] to get familiar with the site.

Comment: Asking for app recommendations would be on-topic on our SoftwareRecs sister site ;) And there are several [gallery apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries) supporting tags (disclosure: link goes to my Android site). Just search the linked page for "tag" (I pointed that out for some, while others might have the feature as well).